# Golang Static files (SVGZ)

Tags: http, go, svgz

Im trying to serve static .svgz files (compressed SVG) with the below script:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":9090", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/srv/www/htdocs/")))
```

im getting the below error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

if i try to fetch the same file through apache, the file is displaying properly.

is there a way to fix that?

Comment: What content type does each server return?

Comment: I also tried with beego , same results

Comment: you can try it: http://97.107.133.88/test.svgz  and http://97.107.133.88:9090/test.svgz

Comment: also http://97.107.133.88/test.svg and http://97.107.133.88:9090/test.svg both are working

Comment: What do you mean both are working? They both display correctly in your browser?

Comment: svg is displaying correctly through dolang server and apache, while svgz gives error through golang server and display correctly through apache

Answer (score 1):

The Go `http.FileServer` doesn't automatically add `Content-Encoding` for sniffed files. If the file is pre-compressed you will need to add the appropriate value.

You can add `Content-Encoding: gzip` to the headers and, and use [`http.ServeFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) in your handler.

Comment: thanks for the answer, any idea how this can be done using beego FW, svgz files are under static folder\

Answer (score 0):

Apache Header (tested in Chrome):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 14:56:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 14:43:34 GMT
ETag: "443-5360731fd11b2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1091
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Go Header (tested in Chrome):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1091
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 14:43:34 GMT
Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 14:54:56 GMT
```

Apache send "Content-Encoding: gzip" in header.

Working code (heavy inspired by https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Upzqsbu2zbo )

https://play.golang.org/p/eWxqHt9QbM

Comment: I'm try in nginx, work with Chrome(51.0.2704.106) and fail on Firefox(45.0.2).
And can't make work again with Go.
No clue for now..